# Basic explanation about 3d models animation in games

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, 3d, scenekit

I have experience in 2D game development, and want to try something with 3D, I try to find some information about 3D model formats, and their animation.

For example If I want running man in 2D I need a sprite sheet (collection of sprites with different positions on them)
But what about 3D? 
if I download 3d model how to make it move?
How to create my own model (in blender for example) moving?

Thank you  for your attention, and for help.
Kind Regards.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An early method, used by games such as Quake: http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html. Store each frame as a separate model and display them one after another; as you'd imagine not very memory efficient, BUT ridiculously easy to implement.

A more advanced method, most commonly used today: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation. Mesh is "wrapped" around virtual "bones"; when the bones are moved the mesh around it deforms accordingly.

Check out **Sebastian Lague** on YouTube; he has quite a good series on Blender Skeletal rigging / animation.

Even more advanced: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline. Computational NURBS surfaces; probably beyond your scope.